# Should we [send] this away?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I came across the [send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/send) tag today and it appears rather ill-defined. The wiki describes it as a *generic tag to use when two or more elements communicate each other using some protocol.*

There are almost 2k questions tagged with it. In many cases, I feel this tag would be better off replaced by something more specific to a given context.

Questions I've found pertain to topics like:

- Questions about HTTP requests
- Questions about calling library code
- Questions about sending emails
- Sending files via messaging apps
- *Send XYZ* forms (where it's literally the name of the form)

etc.

I don't feel the tag adds any valuable information and it's very hard to imagine someone looking for all sorts of questions about *sending stuff* or becoming an expert on the matter.

It seems to me that the number of questions tagged with [send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/send) warrants a burninate request.

Comment: Odd, I know exactly what it means.  Highly selective for the kind of problem where the OP has to struggle with code he did not write.  Hard questions, the abysmal current answer rate is no accident.  It better have a good title to get me to take a look at it :)

Comment: return to [send]er?

Comment: Should the title be "[send]off?"

Comment: @oldtechaa Nah....

Comment: We should [send] the tag to Trogdor.

Comment: Should we [send] this to the oven?

Comment: also [send] might be the little brother of [sento] and [sendmsg] and then should be part of [sockets]